# Start Qt program on login, need "Start in" folder set

Tags: c++, windows, qt, startup, qtwebkit

I have searched and read many other posts related to starting a Qt program (for now, only in Windows) at startup. They have been helpful for a "normal" program. I have the following code right now, it's used with a checkable in the system tray menu:

```
`void MainWindow::setAutoStartup()
{
    QSettings settings(win_autostart_path,QSettings::NativeFormat);
    if (autoStartAction->isChecked()) {
        QString thePath = appPath.replace('/','\\');
        thePath += QDir::separator();
        thePath += app_name;
        thePath += ".exe";
        settings.setValue(app_name, thePath);
    } else {
        settings.remove(app_name);
    }
}`
```

The code does work. I add or removes the correct entry into the registry, and the exe does start after login. However, it's a Qt HTML5 project, so there is also an html folder along side the executable. With the installer created shortcuts, it works, because there is a parameter on the shortcut "Start in:" set to the programs directory. The registry entry however starts the program with a blank/white screen because it doesn't find the html folder, "start in" must be somewhere else for the registry entry.
If I copy one of the shortcuts to the startup folder, it does start correctly, because again, that shortcut has the "Start in:" value set.
So....
Choice a) Anyone know if there's a "start in" parameter that goes along with the reg entry? I've looked everywhere, can't find such a thing
Choice b) Anyone have an example of how to replace below with something that add removes a shortcut to the startup folder? I've seen this as an alternative in many of the related threads, but none of them with an example.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

When Qt Creator generates an HTML 5 application, the source contains the following initialization line:

```
viewer.loadFile(QLatin1String("html/index.html"));
```

The problem is that the path is relative and depends on the process' working directory (I assume "Start in" refers to it). It's bad that the app doesn't work when working directory is not in the app's directory. A correct application should work with any working directory if it doesn't affect its functionality directly. You're experiencing the issue because working directory is set elsewhere on startup.

You need to modify the code so that it uses absolute paths to load resources. If `html/index.html` is in the same directory as the executable file, you can use the following code to construct absolute path to it:

```
QString path = QDir(QApplication::applicationDirPath()).absoluteFilePath(
  QLatin1String("html/index.html"));
viewer.loadFile(path);
```